# How to make angular and PHP project with Scorm 1.2?

Tags: scorm2004, scorm1.2

I need to create a project on javascript and PHP. In this I need to use Scorm 1.2. I am very new to Scrom, how can I use these technologies together?

I have read about Scorm but unable to understand how to use these 3 things together.

Please let me know how I can use angular, PHP & Scorm 1.2 together along with the basic environment creation and coding.

Thanks in advance.